# Xcode5 does not automatically add file to compile sources and crashes after manually adding

Tags: xcode5

This seems to be happening deterministically.

I will add a file graphically through right clicking a group folder and selecting 'new file' or 'add file'. I will add this new file, then will get a linker error while building. After going to the project settings and adding the file to the 'compile sources' manually, Xcode will completely crash, but will still have added the file on reboot.

Has anyone else seen this bug, or know what would be happening here?

Comment: What kind of file is being added? What is the linker error you are getting?

Comment: Same effect for any new implementation files and xibs. Mach-o linker error: OBJC_CLASS not found. It works after crashing so I'm not dying here, but I'm still a bit puzzled.

Comment: Odd. If you can put up the crash long and build log that may tell us something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue, but without the crash. I am adding the file, and checking the target in the inspector for that file, but it won't be listed in the 'Compile Sources' phase. I have to manually add it there. If I go back to the inspector for the file, uncheck the target, then it properly disappears from the 'Compile Sources', but again, will not come back to the 'Compile Sources' by just checking the box.

Restarting Xcode did set things back to normal.